# how can I make id obsecuring into my table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hash

I want to make an id obscuring into my table. I was trying to hash table = md5 or any other hashing algorithm , but how can my id hashed into my `$data` array

my table look like this

[table_mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYaHi.png)

[image]

depending on my id I want to send it to my hash columns, but how can I do it without doing an hidden input?
add product controller

```
public function addProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $min_stock = $this->input->post('min_stock');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $max_stock = $this->input->post('max_stock');
        $data = array(
            'codigo' => $this->codeGenerator(4),
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia_minima' => $min_stock,
            'existencia' => $stock,
            'existencia_maxima' => $max_stock
        );

        if ($data['existencia'] > $data['existencia_minima']) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
        }elseif ($data['existencia_maxima'] < $data['existencia']) {
            $this->json(array('max_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
        }else{
            if (!$this->products->isExistsProduct($data)) {
                $this->products->addProduct($data);
                $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
            }else{
                $this->json(array('duplicate' => 'product already exists'));
            }
        }
    }
```

model

```
public function addProduct($data){
        $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish exactly.  Are you saying that you want to create a hash of the id field and store that in your database in addition to the id?

Comment: yes thats the way I want to

Comment: I suppose you could alter the record after-the-fact with a hash of its id using php's hash function, etc.  Other than that, I don't think you could reliably determine the next inserted id prior to the database insert statement.  In any event, what is the purpose of creating a hash of the id?

Comment: obsecuring. i know with md5() , but how can I detect my id columns in assoc array , and send it directly?